# Subscribed user has their OneSignal subscription status changed to ’User manually opted out’ whenever restarting my app

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I have an app with two environments, **Production(Prod)** and Development(Dev), they both have their respective schemes and individual One Signal accounts.

Everything was working perfectly when working on Dev, after switching to production, I started noticing all subscribed users had their subscribed status changed to `User manually opted out`.

No Code changes had been made in transitioning from dev to Prod. The code is 100% identical. I have spent days trying to find a solution, no headway has been made.

The following are checks we have done in attempts to resolve/investigate the issue.

1. Checking whether we were manually calling `setSubscription(false)` when i start the app.
2. Checking whether our code manually disables notifications when killing the app.

Comment: From my side, I'd like recommend also ask this question [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues). The question is very specific and a third-party SDK is used, perhaps the developers will be able to suggest something

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Thanks, i will ask it there as well.

Comment: i got my issue resolved, i created an issue and was referred to https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/596.